# react-native firestore: Query with where() and orderBy() using different fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I try to access data from my database using the following query:

```
await firestore()
  .collection('col')
  .where('nameLowerCase', '>=', searchString.toLowerCase())
  .where('nameLowerCase', '<=', searchString.toLowerCase() + '\uf8ff')
  .orderBy('nameLowerCase')
  .orderBy('liked', 'desc')
  .startAt(latest || '')
  .limit(15)
  .get();
```

I created the index for it, vut it the result isn't sorted by likes (It is sorted by names).

I tried some other solutions from kind of similar questions. With their help I got to the solution above. It doesn't log a warning or an error but isn't sorted by both orderBy().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query first orders by `nameLowerCase` and only then orders by `liked`, the result will only be ordered on `liked` in cases where multiple documents have the same `nameLowerCase`.

There is no way to change this in the query, so you will have to re-sort the results in your application code after getting them from the database.

Comment: But I am trying to load them in smaller steps to display them while the user continues to scroll. So there is no where to only display those that match the name and then sort them by likes?

Comment: No. Since `>=`/`<=` require that you order on the `nameLowerCase` first, the results will always *first* be in order of `nameLowerCase`. So you will have to re-sort the results in your application code.